# Is there any way to save a keyboard macro in bash?

Tags: bash, macros, readline, inputrc

I would like to permanently save a [keyboard macro](http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/features_7.html#SEC58) that I've recorded using <kbd>C-x (</kbd> and <kbd>C-x )</kbd>. Is there an easy way to "see the source" for my newly recorded macro so that I can bind it to a keyboard shortcut in ~/.inputrc?

I thought `dump-macros` would do it, but it doesn't seem to...

Comment: Well, I'll be damned.  I didn't know about this feature.

Comment: I use gnome-terminal and gconf-editor for configuring keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out it's really not possible, that is, it wasn't possible until tonight!

Since I was curious to dig into the bash source code anyways I went ahead and added this feature :). We'll see if the bash maintainers apply [my patch](https://savannah.gnu.org/patch/index.php?7634).

Answer (score 3):

if it's the last macro defined this should work nicely...

[GNU Bash Handbook](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Keyboard-Macros.html): Print the last keyboard macro defined in a format suitable for the inputrc file.

```
print-last-kbd-macro ()
```

Comment: Holy crap that's the interface I proposed in [my patch](https://savannah.gnu.org/patch/index.php?7634) 10 years ago! I had no idea this actually made it in because my patch never got any comments, but it looks like the bash authors implemented it from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Best I could think of is to try:

```
echo >>.inputrc '<ctrl-x e>'
```

Or if the macro has multiple lines try:

```
echo >>.inputrc <<EOF
<ctrl-x e>
EOF
```

If you have used control characters you may wish to put a sed in there to replace them with the right escape codes for inputrc.

Then go in and edit the last line to have the right prefix and suffix for what you are trying to achieve ...

Comment: save a step, edit .inputrc, position to wherever you want the macro and C-x e to 'type it in'.  But yeah, I'd say this is the best way, of course, you can put it anywhere you want, it's just a bunch of keystrokes.  If you're not in the 'right mode/place/program', you'll likely get misunderstood inputs.  But one would expect that if you didn't use the macro in the right place, right?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that **.inputrc** allows you to just edit your commands in. I tried using `dump-macros` also but couldn't get it to work nor is there much documentation about it. Perhaps it doesn't work or is deprecated.

If there was a command like `xev` for emacs bindings, that would be helpful. In any case, I think your best bet is to edit **inputrc** using the guidelines in the first link below at the bottom of the page. It's quite easy to do.

The second link is an example **inputrc** file for help figuring out how to set up macros.

As an aside, there is also a cool command called `bind -P` which will list all of your macros.

> http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Miscellaneous-Commands.html#Miscellaneous-Commands

Here's an example inputrc file:

> http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Sample-Init-File.html#Sample-Init-File

Comment: Yeah, the whole point is to **not** have to write the macro by hand, but instead print out the one I just recorded...

Comment: turns out `dump-macros` simply prints out what your currently defined macros would output.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to `.inputrc`:

```
alias macro
```